# How can I use a ternary operator mixed with logical OR?

Tags: java

I have one superclass `Foo` and many subclasses `Bar1`..`BarN` that extends the superclass.

```
public Foo { .. }

public Bar extends Foo { .. }

public Bar2 extends Foo { .. }
.......
public BarN extends Foo { .. }
```

I was trying to determine type of child class during runtime then move on to next operation via if, else-if, else statements however I decided to try something new to see if I could reduce number of lines of code so that I came up with below code and there was no compile error. However it didn't cover all the instances of child class.

```
private void doSomething(Foo foo) {
    boolean trigger = false;
    if ( (trigger = foo instanceof Bar ? true : false)
                || (trigger = foo instanceof Bar2 ? false : true) ) {
        if (trigger == true) { // do Bar thing }
        else { // do Bar2 thing }
    }
 }
```

So I said to myself instead of using `boolean` type for trigger variable, let me use int type for the same variable. Such as 1 for `Bar`, 2 for `Bar2`, 3 for `Bar3` and etc. So I re-engineered my code then I got a compile error saying "The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) int,int" in first if statement. I am not sure how to interpret the message.

```
private void doSomething(Foo foo) {
    int trigger = 0;
    if ( (trigger = foo instanceof Bar ? 1 : 0)
                || (trigger = foo instanceof Bar2 ? 2 : 0) ) {
        if (trigger == 1) { // do Bar thing }
        else if (trigger == 2) { // do Bar2 thing }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
int trigger = (foo instanceof Bar) ? 1 :
              (foo instanceof Bar2) ? 2 :
              (foo instanceof Bar3) ? 3 :
               0; // in case it's not an instance of any
```

Answer (score 6):

### Just use the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Rather than telling you how to make it work the way you are trying to do it (for what it's worth, [@Sebastian's answer is a clean way of doing what you've been trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32259160/1768232)), here is a way to do it faster and more legibly.

Use object orientation to your advantage here, rather than wasting all this complexity with likely slow `instanceof` checks. This will allow you to keep the behavior for each implementation of `Foo` to handle every class individually, with the behavior in a separate method so it doesn't get confusing. It's branchless, which means that you don't have to do any `if` calls which can be slow and cumbersome, as you noticed yourself. The code is easier to follow *and* faster.

Here's how it works (this is boilerplate, you don't do any logic here):

```
public interface Foo {
  void accept(FooVisitor visitor);
}

public class Bar implements Foo {
  void accept(FooVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }
}

public class Bar2 implements Foo {
  void accept(FooVisitor visitor) {
    visitor.visit(this);
  }
}
```

Then, in your class that you've been writing, do (this is where the behavior goes):

```
private void doSomething(Foo foo) {
  foo.accept(this);
}

private void visit(Bar bar) {
  // do Bar thing
}

private void visit(Bar2 bar2) {
  // Do Bar2 thing
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice and I will review my design pattern and re-engineer it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, your code (even if it can be made to compile) doesn't seem readable.  One way is to use a `switch` on the class name (requires Java 7+):

```
String className = foo.getClass().getName();
switch(className) {

   case mypackage.Bar:
        // do something

   case mypackage.Bar1:
        // do something
   ...
}
```

Alternatively you can rely on polymorphism where every subclass implements a method declared in `Foo`:

```
class Foo {

   void doSomething() {
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

   @Override
   void doSomething() {
      // something for Bar
   }
}

class Bar1 extends Foo {

   @Override
   void doSomething() {
      // something for Bar1
   }
}
```

If you don't want to change the classes to do this, you can use the Visitor pattern described by @durron597.

Comment: This is by far the slowest way to do this.

Comment: There is another solution using inheritance but requires changing the classes.

Comment: You can also use the Visitor pattern as I suggest in my answer. Your way couples the behavior of the calling class to `Bar`, `Bar1`, etc. which could be completely unrelated. I wouldn't advise doing this especially in cases where `Bar` and so forth are POJOs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the `||` operator with non-boolean types.

Also, you can simplify your if statements to something like the following.

`if (foo instanceof Bar || foo instanceof Bar2) { }`

Comment: That's right, `instanceof` returns a boolean. No need for an intermediate variable.